# Subset dataset with several levels of a categorical variable

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, categorical-data, levels

I want to subset a dataset with several levels of a categorical variable in Rstudio.

With the function "subset" I am able to do it with just one level

`new_df<-subset(df, df$cat.var=="level.1")`

How do I subset with more than one levels?

Comment: You can use the `%in%` membership operator with a list of the factor levels you want to retain rows for. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%`.

This is a membership operator that you can use with a vector of the factor levels of `cat.var` which you would like to retain rows for.

```r
new_df <- subset(df, df$cat.var %in% c("level.1", "level.2"))
```

For example

```r
df <- data.frame(fct = rep(letters[1:3], times = 2), nums = 1:6)

df

# This is our example data.frame
#   fct nums
# 1   a    1
# 2   b    2
# 3   c    3
# 4   a    4
# 5   b    5
# 6   c    6

subset(df, df$fct %in% c("a", "b"))

# Subsetting on a factor using %in% returns the following output:
#   fct nums
# 1   a    1
# 2   b    2
# 4   a    4
# 5   b    5
```

Note: Another option is to use the [`filter`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) function from [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) as follows

```r
library(dplyr)

filter(df, fct %in% c("a", "b"))
```

This returns the same filtered (subsetted) dataframe.